# org.apache.thrift: Invalid method name: 'authenticate'

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, accumulo

I am running some basic Accumulo code from the user manual that is presenting this error.

A simple google search did not provide anything useful.

### ERROR

```
org.apache.accumulo.core.client.AccumuloException: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid method name: 'authenticate'
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ServerClient.execute(ServerClient.java:77)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ConnectorImpl.<init>(ConnectorImpl.java:67)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.ZooKeeperInstance.getConnector(ZooKeeperInstance.java:215)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.ZooKeeperInstance.getConnector(ZooKeeperInstance.java:221)
    at AccumuloTest.main(AccumuloTest.java:21)
```

### CODE LOG

```
13/09/01 15:21:38 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.1.2 sessionTimeout=30000 watcher=org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooSession$ZooWatcher@76caf6c1
13/09/01 15:21:38 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server ubuntu.home/192.168.1.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)
13/09/01 15:21:38 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to ubuntu.home/192.168.1.2:2181, initiating session
13/09/01 15:21:38 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server ubuntu.home/192.168.1.2:2181, sessionid = 0x140dae2a7000128, negotiated timeout = 30000
```

I can do an SSH session into the accumulo box, and then run sudo ./accumulo shell -u  -p  and get into the shell instance.  I cannot use the same username and password to authenticate into the accumulo instance through code.  Is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today. It turns out I was connecting with Accumulo 1.5 jars to a Accumulo 1.4 instance. After updating my client jars to match the server version I was able to get past this issue.